# Django WSGIScriptAlias does not work properly

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Im running my Django app with apache and mod_wsgi. I wanted to run my app from a subdirectory - lets say example.com/test.

I've configured my django.conf as shown below, but it does not work properly. It does run Django, but instead of showing me a "home" is shows django's 404. When I have WSGIScriptAlias pointng to / it works fin on exmaple.com, but with /test example.com shows apache page.

```
Alias /static /home/trailslash/test/static
<Directory /home/trailslash/test/static>
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/trailslash/test/testproject>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /test /home/trailslash/test/testproject/wsgi.py process-group=testproject
WSGIDaemonProcess testproject python-path=/home/trailslash/test:/home/trailslash/test/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup testproject
```

bottom line...

with this config: example.com points to apache home page and example.com/test runs Django but Django expects /test as part of its app not as its root.

Thanks for your help.